# Bypass Before Update trigger

Tags: apex

I have a trigger (Before Update Account) that have to work only if I click in my botton that is conected in a flow.

So I created a checkbox field called  "Run_code__c". The standard value  is false.

What I was thinking to do: 
1-  I set Run_code__c value to "true" in my flow and my trigger have to run 
2 -  Otherwise, if  Run_code__c  is false, my code won't run

But setting  Run_code__c  = true  it's an update and the trigger will block it anyway haha

Do you have an Idea for my code only runs if the flow is running?

Comment: I would revisit this approach based on Salesforce recommendation of one automation tool per object: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_considerations_design_bestpractices.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done:

**Class**

```
   public class MyClass{

     public static boolean runCode = false;

     public static void Method1 (List accs){

       for(Account acc:accs) {  
          if(runCode ==true){ //Do stuff }   
         else { acc.addError('You can only change the record by the  botton'); }
       }
     }

    @InvocableMethod
    (label='Autorize Flow' description='Make Flow update the record' category='Account')
    public static void Method2 (){
       
      runCode =true;
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account (Before Update) {

   MyClass.Method1(trigger.new);

}
```

P.s: I deleted "Run_code__c". I'm not using anymore. 
So in the flow, before update the record, I put an Apex Action.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the value in the before update

for(Account acc:trigger.new){
if(acc.run_code__c){
//Do stuff
}
}

Or dependant on your org data size switch to flow and remove the trigger entirely

Comment: I want to do it, but my code is :

for(Account acc:trigger.new){ if(acc.run_code__c){ //Do stuff }
else{acc.addError('MsgError'} }

And it have to work in a Before Update Trigger... How can I change run_code__c in the flow if the trigger will block it?

Comment: you need to look at the trigger context as a part of it.

trigger.isbefore && trigger.isupdate

so then if run_code__c = true the before update will run - not convinced you should include the else on this as that will prevent your flow from completing.

if you are doing this in a flow I'd be more included to not include the trigger and instead handle the process in the flow. that way you don't have to worry about the trigger

Comment: I don't know if i understood, but I can't do it totally in the flow, because I have to block people to edit the record without clicking in the botton